What standards did velocipedes have when they were invented?
It seems from the wikipedia page that velocipedes were one DIY that was copied by many others. They say about the first example by Baron Karl von Drais:

This design was welcomed by mechanically minded men daring to balance, and several thousand copies were built and used, primarily in Western Europe and in North America.

What standards were they built around? I'd guess that they re-used wheels from horse-drawn carriages, but when did they establish a standard for producing them, like "16 inch wheels" or "100 millimeter hub spacing"?

Congrats - your post hit the HNQ !

The word "standard" May not mean, in this case, what you are thinking.
It means "what to be like".
The original, in this case, was the standard.

No, the OP's use of standard clearly corresponds to one of the dictionary definitions (used or accepted as normal or average). I am not sure exactly how you mean what to be like, but if you mean it in the sense of being the best, then it's extremely unlikely that the first example of a complex object is the best.

Oh, like white out, or a bic lighter. They are standards. Even if they don't follow any themselves.
anything that is the first of it's kind, is considered a standard
You would be correct in saying it didn't have standards to follow, so the "hobby horse" became it.
Karl von Drais invention. The standard of it's day.

No, we would normally say prototypical for the first or original form of something. It might set the standard for all the stuff that followed it, but that event is unusual enough that we'd typically say that explicitly. You know, according to the Smithsonian, the first known velocipede may not even have had steering.

It was definitely  prototypical  and also archtypical* of what followed..
That does not preclude it from being THE standard. (what to be like)
*relating to or denoting an original that has been imitated.

As you say they were DIY objects, works of craftsmanship, and therefore they had no real standard to follow.
And no, horse drawn carriages wheels were too bulky for a man powered vehicle; they had to be scaled down.
Once some set of proportions which worked decently was found, it was followed or copied more or less strictly. One doesn't really need standards until quick mass production is needed.

Cart wheels also had no standard size, usually. The local wheelwright might have used a few sizes, but the next village would have different sizes.

Before Eli Whitney (who had previously invented the cotton gin) pioneered the use of interchangeable parts in his firearm factory in 1798, it would not have been unusual to have significant variation between even samples coming out of the same factory.

Not only were carriage wheels too bulky, they were the wrong shape.  Carriage (and wagon) wheels were generally dished to one side for added strength.  This works fine when you've got two wheels per axle, but with just one, you need symmetric dishing or vertical spokes.

Light carriage wheels very well may have been used .
Cart wheels would have been cumbersome due to the weight bearing differences in construction.

Carts came in many sizes, I am thinking about just dog pulled carts for instance. There were such carts with the wheels under the load bed and others with a load bed on the same height just above the axle. And those I have seen in the same photo so in use in the same area. Add hand pushed carts, with all variations, donkey and pony carts as well as horse drawn carts for all different needs and you will see why you can not ascribe a standard to any of these.
